# Auto login nonce verification check failed

Tags: wordpress, simplemembership

After login with Simple WP Membership this error message shows up:

> Auto login nonce verification check failed!

On a URL
https://hypnosis-joondalup.com.au/membership-login/?swpm_auto_login=1&swpm_user_name=andNomal&swpm_encoded_pw=YW5kTm9tYWw&swpm_auto_login_nonce=9e476485e0.
I have disabled plugins, no change, changed cache settings, no change...

Disabling plugins, same result.
Adding after login page...
Exclude the pages from cache.
Still same error message: Auto login nonce verification check failed!
But the new member gets the email and the login works.